# Fragment Load as Item in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

> I have an Array with Dynamic Size and I want to load all elements of
>   array in RecyclerView using adapter For Left to right and right to
>   left Swipe Each Element Of array by Using RecyclerView and I added
>   FrameLayout in Adapter View and created one Fragment and that Fragment
>   mapped on Frame Layout in case of each index of array in adapter
>   during Swipe onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) but
>   this not worked for as slider I can used view pager but view pager not
>   listen each index during swipe that's why i used recyclerview please
>   help to load data in recycler view as slider and also help to load
>   fragment adruptly during swiping
>
> Here Is Adapter Code

```
ArrayList<CourseLessonDetailsData> mCourseLessonDetailsDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        CourseDetailsActivity mActivity;
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

        public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<CourseLessonDetailsData> _courseLessonDetailsDataList , CourseDetailsActivity _activity, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            mActivity = _activity;
            mCourseLessonDetailsDataList = _courseLessonDetailsDataList;
            mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        }

        @Override
        public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // Create a new view by inflating the row item xml.
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.swipe_course_detail_recycler_item_view, parent, false);

            // Set the view to the ViewHolder
            return new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("course_lesson_array", mCourseLessonDetailsDataList);
                bundle.putString("position", position + "");
                swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.swipe_recycler_view_frame_layout, swipeFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCourseLessonDetailsDataList.size();
        }

        // Create the ViewHolder class to keep references to your views public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            public FrameLayout swipe_recycler_view_frame_layout;

            /*
             * Constructor
             * @param v The container view which holds the elements from the row item xml
             */
            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);

                swipe_recycler_view_frame_layout = v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_recycler_view_frame_layout);


            }


        }
```

Comment: "...but view pager not listen each index during swipe" – I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that, but you can set an [`OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) on a `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks For Reply basically i want to load fragments in recyclerview is there any option which i done this behaviour

Comment: Not really. Well, there's no out-of-the-box solution for that, AFAIK, anyway. `RecyclerView`'s main use is for when you have a bunch of items with similar layouts, and those layouts can be recycled with only superficial modifications for the individual items. What you're trying to do is to completely replace each item with a wholly new `View`, which kinda defeats the purpose. Also, every `FrameLayout` would need to have a unique ID, you would have to keep track of which `Fragment` goes where when those items are recycled, detaching and re-attaching them as needed, etc.

Comment: You could certainly try to merge the functionalities of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `RecyclerView.Adapter`, but I'd imagine that would be somewhat complicated, and at least a little shaky. I have a feeling that you can do what you want with just a simple ViewPager and `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: I want to load one fragment for multiple time with different data basically